# Database Design Strategy Help

Tags: database-design

Thanks for reading this.   I’ve completely overthought this so I’m hoping to get some feedback.

I have a customer table (custID, statusID), a notes table (custID, noteID), an action table (custID, actionID, noteID)  and a status table (custID, actionID, noteID).

The notes table contains self-referential hierarchical data (like a conversation or a forum with a parent note).

Here are the scenarios:

Every customer has a status (like Approved) but they only have one current status.

A customer might have an action that requires a status update (i.e. credit review leading to an increase in credit)

Any user can record notes about a customer

An action will require one parent note.

Any status change will require one parent note.

Here’s where I’m stuck:  I’m thinking I’m getting myself into a data spiral where everything references something else in a random way.  I need to look up a customer and have all the notes available so that was the thinking with my initial design but something seems not right.

I appreciate any thoughts and feedback on this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is, I'm afraid. Try writing a query (even if in pseudo-SQL) that retrieves what you need, and you will quickly see if your model works. Visualizing the model (e.g. as an ERD) also helps.

Comment: @mustaccio - Good idea -- I went down the rabbit hole and totally lost the form follows function aspect.  I'll amend my question.